# Yii2 $model->save() не работает

Tags: php, yii2

Пытаюсь осваивать Yii2 на одном небольшом внутреннем проекте.
Возникла проблема, перестала сохраняться модель.
В чем может быть проблема:
Модель:

```
<?php

namespace app\models;
use Yii;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yii\base\Model;
use yii\web\UploadedFile;

//Класс описывающий модель рассылок
class Send extends ActiveRecord 
{
    //public $id; //ID рассылки
   // public $type; //Тип рассылки
         /**
     * @var UploadedFile
     */
    public $baseFile;
    public $baseText;

    public static function tableName()
    {
        return '{{%send}}';
    }
    //RULES
    public function rules(){
        return [
            ['type', 'required'],
            [['baseFile'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => true, 'extensions' => 'txt, doc, docx'],
        ];
    }



    public function uploadBase()
    {
        if ($this->validate()) {
            $this->baseFile->saveAs('../base/' . $this->baseFile->baseName .date('Y_m_d_H_i'). '.' . $this->baseFile->extension);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Метод контроллера:

```
<?php 
namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\web\Response;
use yii\web\Controller;
use app\models\User;
use app\models\Send;
use yii\web\UploadedFile;

class SendController extends Controller
{
    public $layout = 'client_panel';

    public function actionWatext(){       
         if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {

            $model = new Send(); 
            //Если модель валидна, то переводим на страницу лога рассылок
            if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())){
                $model->baseFile = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'baseFile');
                $model->type = 'WA_text';
                $model->user_id = Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
                $model->text  = $_POST['Send']['text'];

                if(!empty($_POST['Send']['baseText'])){
                    $model->base_text = $_POST['Send']['baseText'];

                    }

                if($_POST['send_date'] == 'Выбрать дату'){
                    $model->date = $_POST['send_date_calendar'];
                }
                else{
                    $model->date = 'Сразу';
                }
                    if(!empty($model->baseFile)){

                            $model->uploadBase();
                            $model->base_file = '../base/' . $model->baseFile->baseName .date('Y_m_d_H_i'). '.' . $model->baseFile->extension;
                        }

                  if ($model->save()) {   
                       return $this->redirect(['client/allsend']);
                 }
                 else{
                     return 'errro';
                 }


            }//Иначе генерируем форму
            else{
                return $this->render('watext',['model' => $model]);
            }
         }
         else{
            return $this->redirect(['site/index']);
         }
    }

}
```

Comment: Скорей всего ошибка валидации, поставьте вместо `return 'errno';` `print_r($model->errors);` и посмотрите ошибки.

Comment: Так, с этим разобрался. Неверное расширение у файла было.
Но вылезла другая ошибка: finfo_file(C:\OSPanel\userdata\temp\php2AD9.tmp): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: может папку надо создать `C:\OSPanel\userdata\temp` ? Хотяя, в какой строчке кода эта ошибка выскакивает?

Comment: Раньше работало,без создания папок.
Там ошибки не в моих фалах выскакивают, а в файла х yii.
in C:\OSPanel\domains\wa.webcom\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\helpers\BaseFileHelper.php at line 158

Comment: Я думаю это из-за того что при model->save() опять вызывается валидация, юи пытается проверить файл baseFile, но временный файл уже удалён. Можно в функции `uploadBase()` при сохранении файла добавить флаг чтобы временный файл не удалялся сразу - `$this->baseFile->saveAs('../base/' . $this->baseFile->baseName .date('Y_m_d_H_i'). '.' . $this->baseFile->extension, false);`.
Но лучше поменять логику валидации - валидировать тут - `if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()){`, в `function uploadBase()` валидацию убрать, и при сохранении тоже убрать - `$model->save(false)`

Comment: Огромное спасибо. Пока сделал по 1 варианту вашему. А про логику щас почитаю, попробую вникнуть полностью.